# Maven WAR - sources are not getting compiled

Tags: java, web-applications, maven

Greetings,

I am trying to build my web application with maven but I ran into some difficulties.

Maven assembles my war file and puts everything into its place except for the compiled classes. It seems like my sources are not even getting compiled.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
         src
         src/main
         src/main/java
         src/main/java/com
         src/main/java/com/test
         src/main/java/com/test/applications
         src/main/java/com/test/applications/TestApplication.java
         src/main/resources
         src/main/webapp
         src/main/webapp/media
         src/main/webapp/media/someimages.jpg
         src/main/webapp/styles
         src/main/webapp/styles/somecss.css
         src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
         src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
         src/main/webapp/scripts
         src/main/webapp/scripts/jquery
         src/main/webapp/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.5.js
         pom.xml
```

and my pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>TestApp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
    <finalName>TestApp</finalName>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The assembled ware file looks ok except that the WEB-INF/classes folder is empty. I'm building with Jenkins and Maven 3.0.2.

Any help would be very much appreaciated.

Best Regards,
Chris

Comment: Do you find `WEB-INF/lib/TestApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`? if so, then it means it have package them up into jar file instead.

Comment: Sadly not... the WEB-INF/lib folder is empty as well.

Comment: Are you sure that Jenkin uses "mvn clean install" command to clean and compile the codes? I have no idea if it still doesn't work. Do you have problem compiling code without using Jenkin?

Comment: Thanks after some testing around I found out that I had still the old goals configured that I was using with the war plugin. I removed the war:war and now it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be solved:

As mentioned in the comment I had still some old configuration for the jenkins build job where it would use the goal war:war to build the project.

After removing this it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem(except that I'm not using jekins).
NOTE: I used the maven webapp creation:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DgroupId=myGroupID -DartifactId=myArtifactID
```

The webapp project folder structure had a this folder: 'src/main/resources' wich all my sources(.java files) were in.

as i changed the 'resources' folder name to 'java'(meaning 'src/main/java') by a friend sugestion, all I had to do is to call 'mvn clean install' to have a war file containig compiled classes.

hope my answer is detailed enough....